# How can I customize code generation in QT Creators refactoring tool?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm using Qt Creator 5.15.2, with Qt 6.0.1.

I'd like to customize the code generated by the refactoring tool to better match my own coding style. For example, "Generate Missing Q_PROPERTY Members" produces a setter that looks like this:

```
void setX(int x)
{
    if (m_x == x)
        return;

    m_x = x;
    emit xChanged(m_x);
}
```

I'd prefer the generated code to look like this:

```
void setX(int x)
{
    if (x != m_x)
    {
        m_x = x;
        emit xChanged(m_x);
    }
}
```

Where can I find the templates/snippets the refactoring tool uses to generate code?

Comment: That implementation is part of the QtCreator cppeditor plugin: https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator/blob/master/src/plugins/cppeditor/cppquickfixes.cpp so you could edit the code, compile it and install (replace it)

Comment: As an alternative, one could use [custom code snippets](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-completing-code.html#completing-code-snippets).